# target selector not working

Tags: css, angularjs

I don't know if the problem is related to Angular or I'm making a mistake.
I have an `<article id="about">`, a link `<a href="#about">` and I'm trying to style the targeted element with

```
:target{
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

when I click the link the article should have a red border, shouldn't it?. When I click the link the URL off course changes from `/company` to `/company#about` but nothing happens, I also checked in the console with JQuery `$(':target')` and it returns `null`.
I thought that maybe it's Angular related, where routing mechanism interferes with some default behavior. I'm using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, Angular 1.1.4 and Chrome26.
**EDIT:** Finally got a non-working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VCAVf/) , it works until I inject $location in `app.run()`.

Comment: Can you provide a demo of it not working?  It looks like it works to me:  http://tinker.io/e74a5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a browser bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83490

See also the last section at http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but:

I think the click event may be returning "false".
That is to say, some code runs, and the default link clicking behaviour is over-ridden.

Try entering the page url, with the hash at the end, into an empty tab. If your :target css works in that case, you'll know it's a javascript thing.

Perhaps the framework adds a class, or some other identifier, which you could easily style? Or maybe if you inspect the DOM, a reference to it is stored in some object, which you could style with jQuery?

Comment: routing inside angular must override the default behavior of links but I don't think I can control it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put target="_self" in the a tag it will solve the issue with the angular routing as long as HTML5 mode is enabled.